# How to set the sudoers in centos desktop?

Tags: linux, centos, sudo

In centos6.8, even set the default desktop background need the root password, then I use sudo function in my company 500 laptops.

```
james01   ALL=(ALL)      NOPASSWD: sbin/route, /sbin/ifconfig, /bin/ping, /sbin/dhclient, /usr/bin/net, /usr/bin/rfcomm, /usr/bin/wvdial, /sbin/iwconfig, /sbin/mii-tool,/bin/rpm, /usr/bin/up2date, /usr/bin/yum
```

1.How to avoid user to edit /sbin/iptables? sudoers has no syntax as `!/sbin/iptables`
2.How to set 500 laptops with the different username,like robin01,marry01?
3.Is there a sudoers file as classic example to control user right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use '!' to negate commands, users, etc. However, you must be careful. The man page for sudoers carries this warning;

> Limitations of the ‘!’ operator
>   It is generally not effective to “subtract” commands from ALL using the ‘!’ operator. A user can trivially circumvent this by copying the desired command to a different name and then executing that. For example:
>   bill    ALL = ALL, !SU, !SHELLS
>   Doesn't really prevent bill from running the commands listed in SU or SHELLS since he can simply copy those commands to a different name, or use a shell escape from an editor or other program. Therefore, these kind of restrictions should be considered advisory at best (and reinforced by policy).
>   In general, if a user has sudo ALL there is nothing to prevent them from creating their own program that gives them a root shell (or making their own copy of a shell) regardless of any ‘!’ elements in the user specification.

Your example of iptables illustrates this well. If you don't grant **ALL**, then you'd have to explicitly grant permissions to a command or set of commands that would allow them to edit iptables. You don't have to negate any commands *unless you use **ALL**.* It will be extremely  challenging to prevent it otherwise.

Rather than setting policy per 500 users, why not apply it to group(s)? If everyone is in a common group, you can use '%' to denote group. Look at the example in /etc/sudoers for the wheel group.

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

Comment: `%wheel  ALL=(ALL)   ALL`  why do we set a common user with all commands authority? almost same as root.

Comment: That was an example applying a policy to a group. (Read the preceding lines in full.) That said, I am not going to tell anyone what is right or wrong for their environment. The benefit to sudo is that the originating user is still logged with auditd. With a traditional root shell there is zero attribution in a multi-user environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to set that on 500 different laptops. 
You can use some automation tools. 
I suggest you "Ansible"..  It's a clientless tool,  you just need ssh credentials for that. 
Try it,  it will really sort out your work.

If you want I can make script for you. 
If interested please ping.  Happy to help to you.